# Random number generator to go to a gate within a file would open but it says file could not be found

Tags: echo

Hey im not too good at this so i went to google and found some different designs of random genreators although none worked for my purpose im trying to get the number from the generator to be dependent on which gate should open have a look it says this before the gate that has the random generator so i moved it to the gate before and now it just show the same error in the previous gate

```
    set /a _rand=%random% %%5 + 1 >nul
if %_rand%== 1 goto A1
if %_rand%== 2 goto A2
if %_rand%== 3 goto A3
if %_rand%== 4 goto A4
if %_rand%== 5 goto A5
```

this is how the other gates look and they work on thier own '

```
    :A1
Cls
C:user/lokation and file
```

```
@echo off
color B
echo computer online 
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo The time and date is %time% %date%
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo What is your request
echo 1. Start miner
echo 2. Advanced
echo 3. shutdown bot
pause >nul
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%== 1 goto 1
if %input%== 2 goto 2
if %input%== 3 goto 3

:3
Cls 
color 4
echo bot shutting down
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo bot off
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
close

:2
Cls
color A
echo Pleas enter the password
pause >nul
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%== 1234 goto 4
if not %input%== 1234 goto 5

:5 
Cls
color 4
echo Password incorrect
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
pause >nul
exit

:After any task
Cls 
color D
echo What is your new request
echo 
echo 1. chat
echo 2. random pic from gallery
echo 3. go back
pause >nul
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%== 1 goto chat
if %input%== 2 echo gallery picture opening
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
pause >nul
set /a _rand=%random% %%5 + 1 >nul
if %_rand%== 1 goto A1
if %_rand%== 2 goto A2
if %_rand%== 3 goto A3
if %_rand%== 4 goto A4
if %_rand%== 5 goto A5
if %input%== 3 goto start

:4
Cls 
Cls 
color D
echo What is your  request
echo 
echo 1. chat
echo 2. random pic from gallery
echo 3. go back
pause >nul
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%== 1 goto chat
if %input%== 2 echo Gallery pic opening
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
pause >nul
set /a _rand=%random% %%5 + 1 >nul
if %_rand%== 1 goto A1
if %_rand%== 2 goto A2
if %_rand%== 3 goto A3
if %_rand%== 4 goto A4
if %_rand%== 5 goto A5
if %input%== 3 goto start

:A1
Cls
color D
"C:\Users\#####\OneDrive\Dokumenter\mah stuff\gallery\download.jpg"
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto After any task 

:A2
Cls 
color D
"C:\Users\####\OneDrive\Dokumenter\mah stuff\gallery\download2.jpg"
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto After any task

:A3
Cls
color D
"C:\Users\####\OneDrive\Dokumenter\mah stuff\gallery\download3.jpg"
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto After any task

:A4
Cls
color D
"C:\Users\#####\OneDrive\Dokumenter\mah stuff\gallery\download4.jpg"
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto After any task

:A5
Cls
color D
"C:\Users\####\OneDrive\Dokumenter\mah stuff\gallery\unnamed.png"
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto After any task

:1
Cls
color A
echo Starting miner 
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Starting 10%%
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Starting miner 20%%
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Starting miner 35%%
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Starting miner 75%%
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo Starting miner 100%%
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo miner started
ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul
start C:\Users\#####\OneDrive\Skrivebord\Miner\xmrig-6.15.3\xmrig.exe
close
```

Comment: `goto A1` => How will the script know where `A1` is ?   Can you post your complete script ?

Comment: sure had to rename the user because it gave my name here it is .... edit it won't fit in comments added it to the acutal thing

Answer (score 0):

1. The lines containing `ping n- 2 127.0.0.1>nul` do have an error. You will not notice the error because of the `>nul`.

I think this was meant: `ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul`

2. `close` is an unknown statement.

I think you should change this to: `exit`

3. Line #11 `pause >nul` makes your script wait for a key. Is this really needed? because `SET /P ...` wil ask for input, a `PAUSE` just before the input makes no sense.

Probably some other errors exists. But I wish you happy debugging times to find them !

Comment: i did add the pause >nul for the pure reason that it wouldn't close the program as i experienced before thanks for the tips

Comment: It will close the program (a.k.a script) when the script performs an `exit`). If you do not want it to close completely, use `exit /b`. (see: https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html )

Comment: also i just figured out that if i click enter again it's gonna go to the file that i couldn't get to appear even tho it says file not found